# How to use Reactive Outbound Adapter HTTP POST with body

Tags: spring-integration, spring-webflux, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to use the Reactive Outbound Gateway in Spring Integration, but the documentation is not clear at all on how to add a POST body, including the sample tests.

Please help.

When using the WebClient builder you cannot add a POST body (I tried create()), but it doesn't return the WebClient type that's needed.

```
WebClient c = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://myurl.com")
                .build();

//can add a body after doing this, but you this cannot get passed into the method, because it executes the call

c.post()
 .headers(h -> h.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
 .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(m.getPayload()))
 .retrieve()
 .bodyToMono(String.class)
```

This is the example from the Spring docs -- not sure what they are POSTING

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/webflux.html

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "reactiveHttpOutRequest")
@Bean
public WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler reactiveOutbound(WebClient client) {
    WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler =
        new WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler("http://localhost:8080/foo", client);
    handler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
    handler.setExpectedResponseType(String.class);
    return handler;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not sure what they are POSTING

Long story short: the payload of the request message on that `reactiveHttpOutRequest`.

Please, make yourself familiar with  [Enterprise Integration Patterns](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) to be sure that you understand what is message and how it is handled on the service activator. And of course how to give the data for that service activator via sending the message into a channel.

There is no difference what kind of outbound channel adapter you use: it always deals with the message sent to its input channel and its payload.

To be more precise here is a source code of that `WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler` where we set a body into a `WebClient` request:

```
    BodyInserter<?, ? super ClientHttpRequest> inserter = buildBodyInserterForRequest(requestMessage, httpRequest);
    if (inserter != null) {
        requestSpec.body(inserter);
    }
```

This one is used from here:

```
protected Object exchange(Object uri, HttpMethod httpMethod, HttpEntity<?> httpRequest,
        Object expectedResponseType, Message<?> requestMessage, Map<String, ?> uriVariables) {

    WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestSpec =
            createRequestBodySpec(uri, httpMethod, httpRequest, requestMessage, uriVariables);
```

That `exchange()` is called from here:

```
protected Object handleRequestMessage(Message<?> requestMessage) {
```

This `handleRequestMessage()`  is called from the `MessageHandler.handleMessage()`, which, in turn, is called when a `MessageChannel` delivers the message sent into it.

Comment: ok Amazing That makes sense. It just wasn't explicitly clear in the documentation. thank you! Yes I saw the method above and was trying to figure out how it is called.

Comment: The documentation is not a book and does not teach you general concepts which are out of the project scope. In this doc we try to explain what are those components and how they work. Although we have some general explanation in this chapter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#endpoint

Comment: Thanks! One more question. Is there a way to explicitly remove all headers on a message?

Comment: There is a dedicated EI pattern - Header Filter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#header-filter. However this sounds more like a new SO thread with more info to determine your requirements and expectations.

Comment: I will read up and make a new thread if needed. Thank you so much Artem!!